# Running program in an isolated desktop / sandbox with access to original hardware

Tags: windows, sandbox

There is this program "Desktops.exe" by Sysinternals.

Using this program, one can create more desktops.
You can still use the usual file system, it's just another desktop, but it still uses the real machine and its hardware.

Is there a program that does just this plus adds the ability to give this desktop a different Windows date / time?

What I'm looking for is something like VMWare or any other sandbox software but which uses the real graphics cards.

VMWare for example uses an emulation.

Comment: Questions seeking Software recommendations are specifically not within scope here at Superuser.

Comment: You can add multiple clocks but only one can be displayed in the taskbar at all times.  You would have to replace the File Explore shell, but doing so, would make your software inoperable.